# Crosstab query with generic column headings

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is probably quite easy, but I'm stuck on in regardless and my searches didn't come up with anything useful. I have data that currently is in this format:

```
    ID        Code  
|1212050   |   LB   |
|1212050   |   LJ   |
|1212050   |   LK   |
|1212052   |   FB   |
|B12L076   |   CL   |
|B12L076   |   LK   |
```

There are many possible codes, but I need the query to display the first ten (even if the ID only has one) in this format:

```
    ID        Code1    Code2    Code3     
|1212050   |   LB   |   LJ    |   LK   |   
|1212052   |   FB   |         |        |     
|B12L076   |   CL   |   LK    |        |
```

I can easily create a crosstab query that creates a view with the codes as column headings, but that creates to many columns. I need it to have columns with labels of "Code1" through "Code10", regardless of which codes are used in the IDs. Here's the kicker: It has to be in Access sql.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The test group I will be using to test the query is:

```
     ID   Code
 |1212044|  LJ|
 |1212044|  LJ|
 |1212044|  LJ|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  LB|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  HT|
 |1212050|  CL|
 |1212050|  LK|
 |1212050|  LK|
 |1212050|  LK|
 |1212050|  CL|
 |1212050|  LK|
 |1212050|  CL|
 |1212050|  LK|
 |1212050|  CL|
 |1212050|  LK|
 |1212050|  LJ|
 |1212052|  FB|
 |1212052|  FB|
 |1212052|  LB|
 |1212052|  FB|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L076|  CL|
 |B12L076|  LK|
 |B12L103|  LB|
 |B13A072|  CL|
 |B13A072|  LK|
 |B13A072|  HT|
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the test data. From it I see that you have multiple rows containing identical data. Your problem just got harder, because I don't see how to make a SQL query tell the difference between the first and second and third rows showing |1212044|  LJ|.

Comment: The original data table has a three field primary key. The ID is only one of the fields necessary to make it unique. I should have mentioned that. I didn't include those rows because they contain sensative information. When I ran your sql, I substituted the table with a query that grouped it on ID first.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a way to do it all with queries:

Add an index field to your table with an auto-number type

Set up a query to find the smallest index value for each ID

Set up a 2nd query to find the sequence number of each ID / Code combination, calculated as 1+ the record's index minus the index for the ID from the prior query

The 3rd query is then a crosstab from the 2nd query, with ID as the row and the Sequence number as the column - and you can select on sequence numbers <=10 to limit the number of columns.  The "Value" field in the crosstab will have to be calculated as "First" of the Code values, or some other text function.

On further reflection, I think you could combine the 2nd and 3rd queries by doing the calculation described in the 2nd query and using it as the column heading as described in the 3rd query.  I tend to break things up into smaller queries to make each one simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work. The Access tables are deleted and recreated by our Data Management Application and we can't modify the table structure. We can only query it with Access sql queries. We can't even use VBA. It's extremely limited. I have been researching how to add a field to a initial query that has a incrementing counter per ID (so the value would be code1, code2, etc) so that I can use it in the crosstab, but I haven't found a way to do that yet. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I hate to create a new table, but you may need to do so - are you able to run a make table query from your source data, and include an auto-number field in the new table?  (Note - it should be sorted on ID and Code, if the source data isn't.)  If you can do this, the process above should work

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this step by step.

The first step is to join the table to itself in such a way as to list all the distinct pairs of codes under each ID.

That done, we can apply grouping to get each code together with its rank among the codes that fall under the given ID.

In code:

```
Select a.ID, a.Code AS EarlierCode, b.Code AS LaterCode
from [YourTable] AS a
INNER JOIN [YourTable] AS b
ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.Code <= b.Code
```

Save this query as YourPairs.

Now

```
Select ID, LaterCode AS Code, "Code" & Count(*) AS Label
from [YourPairs] 
HAVING Count(*) <= 10
```

Save this second query, then build a crosstab using the Label field as the column label.

Comment: Note that this uses only Access sql queries, as required. I just hope you are allowed to save your Access sql queries.

Comment: I don't know if I'm failing to explain this well or if I simply can't get your sql to work. When I ran the sql (with the my table & field names) it returned only 9 records.

Comment: Just to clarify, there are numerous codes, but each ID can only have a maximum of 10. So, they need a query that shows all the IDs with columns 1 - 10 to hold the codes. All code columns must be there, even if they contain null values.

Comment: Using the example records you included with the question, I would have expected six records, one for each row of your initial table. If you have a bigger test set, could you share it with us?

Comment: Dan, in the definition of the crosstab, predeclare  "Code1" through "Code10" as the column headers. Then you'll have all ten "Code" columns in your output even when some are blank.

Comment: I edited my initial question to add the dataset I'm using to test the queries. When I plugged the sql in to that set, it returned only nine items...did I forget something? Is there a grouping problem?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working solution using Microsoft Access.

Table1 - Contains columns ID and Code

Query1 - Uses Table1 to identify unique combinations of ID and Code

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Code
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.ID, Table1.Code
ORDER BY Table1.ID, Table1.Code;
```

Query2 - Uses Query1 to add a unique Code Sequence

```
SELECT Query1.ID, Query1.Code, 'Code ' & Count([Query1_1].[Code]) AS [Code Seq]
FROM Query1 LEFT JOIN Query1 AS Query1_1 ON Query1.ID = Query1_1.ID
WHERE (((Query1_1.Code)<=[Query1].[Code]))
GROUP BY Query1.ID, Query1.Code
ORDER BY Query1.ID, Query1.Code;
```

Query3 - Uses Query2 to produce the desired crosstab with a limit of 10 Codes per ID

```
TRANSFORM Max(Query2.Code) AS MaxOfCode
SELECT Query2.ID
FROM Query2
GROUP BY Query2.ID
ORDER BY Query2.ID
PIVOT Query2.[Code Seq] In ("Code 1","Code 2","Code 3","Code 4","Code 5","Code 6","Code 7","Code 8","Code 9","Code 10");
```

Results - Using above test data

```
ID         Code 1  Code 2  Code 3  Code 4  Code 5  Code 6  Code 7  Code 8  Code 9  Code 10
1212044    LJ                                   
1212050    CL      HT      LB      LJ      LK
1212052    FB      LB
B12L076    CL      LK
B12L103    LB
B13A072    CL      HT      LK
```